# Difference between extend a class and create instance in another class in php

Tags: php, oop, instantiation

First file:

```
class Class_one {

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function show_name() {
        echo "My Name is Siam";
    }

    public function show_class() {
        echo "I read in class 7";
    }

}
```

Second file:

```
<?php

require_once './Class_one.php';

class Class_two {

    public $class_one;

    public function __construct() {
        $aa = new Class_one();
        $this->class_one = $aa;
    }

    public function history() {
        $this->class_one->show_name();
    }

}

$ab = new Class_two();
$ab->history();
```

What will happen if i don't instantiate class_one in class_two and extend class_one into class_two? Is there any difference?

Answer (score 2):

There's only one potential gotcha here: `Class_two` won't have direct access to `Class_one` private/protected methods and variables. That can be a good thing (encapsulation is where a class does some specific task and you don't want children to interfere with it), but it can also mean you can't get to the data you need.

I would suggest you do `Class_two` as a dependency injection (as shown in your example), however

```
class Class_two {

    public $class_one;

    public function __construct(Class_one $class) {
        $this->class_one = $class;
    }
}
```

Comment: if i follow your suggestion then i need to pass class_one instance / object when i create instance of class_two. Am i right?

Comment: That's what I am suggesting. The only reason to instantiate it in the constructor as you showed, is that it's really an extension of the class (in which case it should be a parent class)

Comment: the term " is that it's really an extension of the class (in which case it should be a parent class) "
i don't understand :(

Comment: If two HAS to instantiate one in a specific way, then two should probably extend one

Answer (score 1):

It should be a semantic difference:

- You use inheritance when relationship between two classes can be expressed with *to be* verb. For example: *My Ford **is a** Car*
- You use association/composition when relationship between two classes can be expressed with *to have* verb. For example: *My car **has an** engine*.

Above rules should be the first consideration when choosing inheritance or association in object-oriented programming. There've been always discussion about avoiding inheritance, and some will argue that you should choose composition over inheritance. See this other Q&A: [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

In terms of pure coding, as [@Machavity on his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41324654/411632) has already said, there could be accessibility limitations when using composition instead of inheritance, but I wouldn't decide which approach to use based on member accessibility.